# How is llvm-cov installed on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: llvm, llvm-cov

I've tried installing both clang-9, clang-9-tools, llvm-9 and llvm-9-tools in order to get the program llvm-cov. None of these packages seemingly contain llvm-cov, which leaves me to wonder what package *does* include it.

How do I install the latest version of llvm-cov on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: The site you want is [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=llvm-cov&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any).

Comment: @arnt Thank's. What is surprising me is that llvm-cov doesn't appear in any package newer than version 6? There seems to be documentation online for newer versions of llvm-cov.

Comment: The [only documentation I see for ubuntu](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=llvm-cov) is from 6.0. Of course llvm-cov remains in the source and in other distributions. If you want to know why, [the build details are in a git repo](https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-llvm-team/llvm-toolchain.git%20-b%206.0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When installing using `apt-get install llvm-9`, `llvm-cov` will be installed with a suffix of the version number as well.

It seems the main registry of `llvm` installs just `llvm v6`.

Comment: This worked! llvm-cov showed up under /usr/lib/llvm-9/bin after running apt-get install llvm-9